# x3d file export different than anticipated need other format to import models

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, blender, x3d

I want to use blender to create my 3d models and then import them into my opengl project. I have a class named “Mesh” that also contains a list of sub Meshes.

In blender, I create three box meshes literally stacked on top of each other. The first is called “body” the next “neck” and finally “head.” In blender I simply went to "Add" then "Cube" and then moved the cube only vertically in the **Y** direction.

When I export the file as a x3d these are the results I get in the file... just as expected.

```
<Transform DEF="body_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"
                  ...>
<Transform DEF="neck_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="0.000000 2.247268 0.000000"
                  ...>
<Transform DEF="head_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="0.000000 4.824310 0.000000"
                   ...>
```

Now for my opengl project I want the main mesh to be the body, a submesh the neck and then a submesh of the neck, I want to be the head. So in blender, in the scene tree view, I drag the head into the neck and the neck into the body so I have this...

```
body     
|_______Neck     
           |_________Head
```

As a result, I expect the translation in the y dimension to change and become relative. Instead this is what I get...

```
<Transform DEF="body_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"
                   ...>
<Transform DEF="neck_TRANSFORM"
                       translation="0.000000 0.000000 2.247268"
                      ...>
<Transform DEF="head_TRANSFORM"
                           translation="0.000000 0.000000 2.577042"
                           ...>
```

As you can see, instead of being in the **Y** dimension, blender exported it and put the changes in the **Z** dimension.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? These are the results I anticipated...

```
<Transform DEF="body_TRANSFORM"
                   translation="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"
                   ...>
<Transform DEF="neck_TRANSFORM"
                       translation="0.000000 2.247268 0.000000"
                       ...>
<Transform DEF="head_TRANSFORM"
                           translation="0.000000 2.577042 0.000000"
                           ...>
```

I will also take any other ideas how to get models into my project, so long as I can create the submeshes relationship in blender.

Comment: add a model matrix that swaps the Y and Z axis?

Comment: I am really interested in finding out what is the problem because as my models get more and more complex I want to anticipate consistency in the files that Blender produces... As you can see 2.577+2.24 adds up to the 4.82, so the logic of the sub meshes is there, but swapping those dimensions don't make any sense in my opinion.